# Role based CRUD with Nodejs mongodb

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, user-roles

I am making web application like shop. There is **admin**, and **moderator**. Moderators add, delete, update, and retrieve the products belongs to them. Admin can have all permission for any operations.

Permission middleware for admin

```
module.exports = function (req, res, next) { 
  if (!req.user.isAdmin) return res.status(403).send('Access denied.');
  next();
}
```

Delete method

```
exports.Delete = async (req, res) => {
  try {
    let product= await Products.findById(req.params.id);
    if (!product) return res.status(404).json({ msg: 'Item not found' });

    // Make sure user owns product
    if (product.user.toString() !== req.user.id ) {
      return res.status(401).json({msg: 'Not authorized'});
    }
    await Products.findByIdAndRemove(req.params.id);
    res.json({msg: 'Product removed'});
  } catch (err) {
    console.error(err.message);
    res.status(500).send('Server Error');
  }
}
```

These are sample from my codes, I used above middleware to delete method, but the result is 'Not authorized'.
I want to do this without 3rd party libararies

Comment: req.user.id is an instance of ObjectId from Mongoose, or a String?

Comment: It is a string,

Comment: Well then the result should be as expected. Is your ```req.user``` configured correctly? Does it include all the required fields?

Comment: For me, Yes. I think I have done correctly. but the result shows as above. Could you give me any example how to do any permission middleware?

Comment: You could go with [Passport](http://www.passportjs.org/), a very popular middleware. Their documentation is good.